# Adding maven to PATH on macOS Big Sur

Tags: java, macos, maven, maven-3

How to add Apache Maven to PATH on macOS Big Sur permanently ? I have downloaded and unzipped maven.

Answer (score 3):

If you have downloaded maven from [apache](https://maven.apache.org), and extracted the binary.zip, first you need to check your terminal type. To view it open your terminal and type,`echo $SHELL`
Then you will get your terminal type(zsh or bash).
If its bash open the `.bash_profile` file by,
either `open ~/.bash_profile` or `vi ~/.bash_profile`.
Then add the apache maven path to it by first declaring the `MAVEN_HOME` and `M2_HOME`.

```
export MAVEN_HOME = '/{your-maven-location}/apache-maven-3.8.2/'
export M2_HOME = '/{your-maven-location}/apache-maven-3.8.2/'
```

Then add those to the `PATH` variable by,

```
export PATH="$MAVEN_HOME/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$M2_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

After adding these lines save the .bash_profile.
Then in terminal type `source ~/.bash_profile` to source the file.
Now, if you type `echo $PATH` you can see the maven is added to your path.

And do the same thing for .zshrc file by opening it using `open ~/.zshrc` or `vi ~/.zshrc`.

You can either change .bash_profile or .zshrc file depending on the shell you have. But,I would recommend you to add the path variable to both files.

If you are having any sourcing issues, give file changing privileges by, `sudo chown {your-username} ~/.bash_profile` or `sudo chown {your-username} ~/.zshrc`.
You can find your username by `ls -al /Users`