# maven build failure package com.sun.tools.classfile does not exist

Tags: java, macos, maven, maven-compiler-plugin

I have a maven project which needs

```
import com.sun.tools.classfile.Dependencies;
```

I can build it successfully in IntelliJ. But when I build it outside using "mvn clean install". I got the error "Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project ...  `package com.sun.tools.classfile` does not exist".

Package `com.sun.tools.classfile` belongs to $JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar. and it exists under that directory. Seems that Intellij can find it but maven build could not find it. Anyone knows why it could happen?

My machine is Macbook pro. Here are the java version and maven verion on my box.

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home
java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_292-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.292-b10, mixed mode)

mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.8.1 (05c21c65bdfed0f71a2f2ada8b84da59348c4c5d)
Maven home: /Users/wuming/apache-maven-3.8.1
Java version: 1.8.0_292, vendor: AdoptOpenJDK, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.15.7", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Thanks

Comment: As far as I remember `tools.jar` is part of the JDK, not of the JRE and the path Maven uses points to the JRE.

Comment: @Robert, you are right that tools.jar is part of the JDK. But from https://maven.apache.org/install.html, the output of mvn -version is expected, it should point to the JRE, not JDK.

Comment: One question is coming into my mind. Why do you need that class? What kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @khmarbaise, thanks for pointing that out. I actually don't need to use that class. It was added automatically by intellij

Comment: If it was added by IDEA you have used a class `Dependencies` in your code...

Answer (score -1):

If you added maven via `brew install maven` you will get this type of issue.

Better to get the apache maven and setup the path variables accordingly.

To setup the path variables check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66034065/adding-maven-to-path-on-macos-big-sur/69463779#69463779)

Comment: No, you simply need to set up the path with your homebrew cellar location. Its not actually an issue.