# Upgraded to Big Sur 1.6. Now maven shows this Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher

Tags: java, maven, macos-big-sur

After upgrading to Big Sur 1.6 I had to run Maven. mvn clean install.  I got the following error Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher

I followed the suggestion offered here. [Maven error : Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33133809/maven-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-codehaus-plexus-classworlds)

No luck.

I tried removing and reinstalling both maven and java to the latest stable releases (Maven 3.8.3 and Java 14).  That didn't work either.

I am finding others having these problems, but have not found a solution that works.

Has anyone found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed the maven using `brew install maven` and haven't setup the path variables accordingly you would get these types of issues.

To fix this remove the maven you installed via `brew` and download the apache maven binary zip and extract it. Then setup the path variables as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66034065/adding-maven-to-path-on-macos-big-sur/69463779#69463779)

Same goes for java. You should remove any sort of JDK you have installed using brew and download and install a JDK from a .dmg file. I would recommend using Oracle JDK if you can.

After doing that setup the JAVA_HOME and add it to the PATH variable.

After that it should work.

Comment: I found that with 11.6 I had to move all paths to home/.zshrc file

Comment: Yes it depends on the shell you are using. First check the shell by typing `echo $SHELL`. Even if you are using the zsh shell, it is better to set up them for bash shell too. Because if you type `vi ~/.bash_profile` you can see there is a file.